# Select sum of data between two dates in another table SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose I have a table `Tbl_Dates_Weekly` and another table `Tbl_Data`.

`Tbl_Dates_Weekly` looks something like

```
WeekBegin      WeekEnd
03-01-2000     07-01-2000
10-01-2000     14-01-2000
.
.
.
```

In my other table `Tbl_Data` it looks something like

```
DateDate      Volume
03-01-2000    100
04-01-2000    200
05-01-2000    300
06-01-2000    150
07-01-2000    340
.
.
.
```

I would like to calculate the sum of Volumes in a given period. In this case, it is the sum of volumes between the given dates of `Tbl_Dates_Weekly`. I.e. from the first week above, I would like the output to be `1090`. How can I obtain this from the two tables?

Comment: What database provider?

Comment: Microsoft access

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(C.VOLUME)
FROM TBL_DATA AS C INNER JOIN
     Tbl_Dates_Weekly AS W
     ON C.DateDate BETWEEN W.WeekBegin AND W.WeekEnd
WHERE W.WeekBegin='20000103' AND W.WeekEnd='20000107'
```

Something like that

Comment: Syntax error in FROM clause, also those dates are static. They need to be representative of each row in `Tbl_Dates_Weekly`

Comment: Then I guess it would be nice if you provide desired output, because "I.e. from the first week above, I would like the output to be 1090" and the above query produces it

Comment: When I enter `SQL view` in microsoft access and paste that code in exactly, It gives me an error saying `Syntax error in FROM clause.` and highlights `JOIN` afterwards.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That still does not work. I get an error saying `Between operator without And in query expression 'C.DateDate BETWEEN W.WeekBegi'.` Also, I would like it to be between the dates in the table, not specifically `20000103` and `200000107`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get all weeks and data corresponding to that weeks, you need to use different type of join => `left join`.

```
SELECT tdw.WeekBegin, tdw.WeekEnd, Sum(Nz(td.Volume, 0)) AS WeeklyVolume
FROM Tbl_Dates_Weekly tdw
    LEFT JOIN Tbl_Data td ON ((td.DateDate>=tdw.WeekBegin) AND (td.DateDate<=tdw.WeekEnd))
GROUP BY tdw.[WeekBegin], tdw.[WeekEnd];
```

Result:

```
WeekBegin   WeekEnd WeeklyVolume
2000-01-03  2000-01-07  1090
2000-01-10  2000-01-14  0
```

For further details, please see: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)